# Beamer uncover text that was invisible and then make transparent

Tags: beamer, overlays

I'm trying to incrementally uncover items in an enumerate environment. The text should be invisible before it is uncovered. After each element is shown it should be covered again, but this time I want it to be transparent. I have the following which accomplishes what I desire:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \setbeamercovered{
    still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
    again covered={\opaqueness<1->{50}}
  }
  \begin{itemize}[<+>]
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \item third item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `\setbeamercovered{}` command I used is a bit complicated, and seems a bit excessive when I don't want to specify multiple items for `still covered` or `again covered`. Is there a way to do this that is simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see what is wrong with your current solution, but perhaps you would prefer the following?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-| uncover@+>]
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \item third item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```